# "the corner of his next speech" meaning in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> ... "You're - you're not a hoax, then?"
>
> It had been his last, desperate hope.
>
> "No," said Fudge gently. "No, I'm afraid I'm not. Look."
>
> And he had turned the Prime Minister's teacup into a gerbil.
>
> "But," said the Prime Minister breathlessly, watching his teacup chewing on **the corner of his next speech**, "but why - why has nobody told me - ?"
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince</sub>

I'm not quite sure what "**the corner of his next speech**" means exactly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PM is drinking tea and with the written or printed copy of his next speech in front of him—presumably he's working on it. When the teacup is turned into a gerbil it looks for possible food and is now chewing on a corner of the paper.